# Open Source Alternative to ASP.NET Commercial Uber-Grids 2013

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for an open source alternative to

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Grid/

my employer wants something of similar level but is unwillig to pay for those. I need soemthing that can be easily integrated in asp.net with datatable.

I ask here after throughly searching the internet and finding all alternatives as horrible to say the least.

Comment: So what you really are asking is, you want a _free_ version of the control. The "free" in opensource is from `free`dom, not cheap/inexpensive.

By the way, you should really convince your superiors to pay for it. In the long run, its a better investment than trying to figure out how to fix any bugs that might arise in your alternate solution.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid way to go rubbing salt into my wounds. not all programers work in programmer friendly companies.
some of us have hard time out here. perhaps in your programer heaven you can tell your boss something like that. here il just become jobless.

Comment: I didn't mean it that way, I meant that there is a difference between _open source_ and _the price of software_. In the long run, for a business you are better off paying for it because it will be better value. Believe me, the vast majority of programmers work with idiot bosses - except for those blessed enough to work in companies that have software engineering as their core. I sympathize with you but this is something that everyone deals with.

Comment: @NahumLitvin Look at http://www.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

Try slickgrid, a javascript/jQuery based grid that can be used in ASP.NET - highly performant and customizable. Please go through the examples in github. You also get good support here in SO.

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

I replaced Telerik RadGrid with Slickgrid in my project a few months back (for performance reasons) and got great results.